# Simulate sending data and receiving using php://input

Tags: php, laravel

I have two routes.

```
Route::get('/receiveSignal', 'SignalController@receiveSignal');
Route::get('/sendSignal', 'SignalController@sendSignal');
```

I want to simulate sending data from `sendSignal` to receiving signal route.

So, in sending signal function I have this:

```
public function sendSignal()
    {
        $data = ['spotid' => '421156', 'name' => 'Test', 'desc' => 'some desc', 'StartofDetection' => '2018-01-17 22:22:22'];

        $dataJson = json_encode($data);

        return $dataJson;

    }
```

How can I change it to receive in `receiveSignal` like this:

```
public function receiveSignal()
    {
        $test = file_get_contents('php://input');

        dd($test);
    }
```

Here I should receive the json to the `receiveSignal` after I enter the http://localhost:8000/sendSignal. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
1. In your route:

```
Route::post('receiveSignal', 'SignalController@receiveSignal');
Route::get('sendSignal', 'SignalController@sendSignal');
```

2. In your sendSignal method

   ```
   public function sendSignal()
   {
       $data = ['key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2'];
       $response = http_post_fields('http://localhost:8000/receiveSignal', $data);
       if (!empty($response)) {
           return view('success'); // or anything else you want to return
       }
       else {
           return view('failed'); 
       }
    }
   ```
3. In your receiveSignal method

   ```
   public function receiveSignal(Request $request)
   {
       $key = $request->input('key');
       $key1 = $request->input('key2');
       //and so on
   }
   ```

Good luck.